# I need VBA help setting the output range in a script to the table value defined in a data table

Tags: excel, vba

I want to take the value of one column on a data table(CellValue column) and have it pasted "x"(URL # Column on same table) number of times.

The issue I am running into is where to paste it.

I can define a single range/table to put the information in but I want to have do so dynamically.

I tried to `Hlookup` a value to define the datatable but could not sort it out. I have the output table value in a column on the same datatable(Table) by changing

```
Set OutRng = Range("URL_Builder[Table]").value'
```

to define a single location like "C38". I get the desired result, but I need it to actually paste the information to the correct table that is listed in the table column.

Below is a sample of the VBA I am using, and a snapshot of the table I am working with.

I have to build this in a mac friendly VBA.

Sample Input Table:
[image: SampleTable]

Sample VBA:

```
Sub CopyData()


Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range



Set InputRng = Range("URL_Builder[[CellValue *Used for Formula*]:[Table]]")
Set OutRng = Range("URL_Builder[Table]").value

For Each Rng In InputRng.Rows
    xValue = Rng.Range("A1").Value
    xNum = Rng.Range("B1").Value
    OutRng.Resize(xNum, 1).Value = xValue
    Set OutRng = OutRng.Offset(xNum, 0)
Next
End Sub
```

Output should be:

[image: SampleOutput]

**I have also tried**

```
Sub CopyData()


Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range

'Sets the input range
Set InputRng = Range("URL_Builder[[CellValue *Used for Formula*]:[Table]]")

'Sets the output range
If Range("URL_Builder[Table]") = "DataTable1[CellValue]" Then
    Set OutRng = Range("DataTable1[CellValue]")
    Else

If Range("URL_Builder[Table]") = "DataTable2[CellValue]" Then
Set OutRng = Range("DataTable2[CellValue]")

End If
End If


For Each Rng In InputRng.Rows
    xValue = Rng.Range("A1").Value
    xNum = Rng.Range("B1").Value
    OutRng.Resize(xNum, 1).Value = xValue
    Set OutRng = OutRng.Offset(xNum, 0)
Next
End Sub
```

This Code will put the information as I need it in a table, but I can't "Hard Code" the table this code has to be able to determine the table based off a cell value

```
Sub CopyData()


Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range

'Sets the input range
Set InputRng = Range("URL_Builder[[CellValue *Used for Formula*]:[Table]]")

'Sets the output range
Set OutRng = Range("DataTable1[CellValue]")


For Each Rng In InputRng.Rows
    xValue = Rng.Range("A1").Value
    xNum = Rng.Range("B1").Value
    OutRng.Resize(xNum, 1).Value = xValue
    Set OutRng = OutRng.Offset(xNum, 0)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: can you show what the output should look like on your table?

Comment: The out puts should be on 2 seperate tables, one named "DataTable1" the other named "DataTable2" both have a column named "CellValue"

These would be on DataTable1 "CellValue" column
Test1
Test2
Test2
Test2


These would be a completely different data table named 'DataTable2' in the "CellValue" column
Test4
Test4
Test4
Test4
Test4

Comment: photo may help to make sure there is no miscommunication. You gave us a starting table - show what the final output should look like as it relates to the inputs you provided. Sorry, looking to do solution but I don't think there is enough info to provide a answer that wouldn't need a lot of modifications

Comment: I updated the post, hopefully you can see the photo, it will not let me imbed the picture yet, since I am new to posting here.